# Select record starting with a particular letter and a particular penultimate letter

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
|String|

|daaaaba|
|daaaaaaaaaba|
|eeeeeba|
|dffffbab|
```

Consider the following record from `my_table`. I want to select all the records that start with `d` and the letter before the last (penultimate) is a `b`.

So I want to select: `daaaaba` and `daaaaaaaaaba`.

My query:

```
select string from my_table where string like 'd%' and ... ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
select string from my_table where string like 'd%b_'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `'d%d_'` :

```
select string from my_table where string like 'd%d_'
```

underscore `_` will specify the need for exactly one character after `'d'`.

See: [Like - Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm)

> An underscore (_) in the pattern matches exactly one character (as
>   opposed to one byte in a multibyte character set) in the value.